# How to call MVC Partial View inside using Embers Js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new in development embers js with MVC .

Struggling with how to call partialview from  .cshtml Page.

Parial View Using Embers Js .

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">

        {{#each item in limitedContent }}
        <div>
            <div style="width:800px;margin:0 auto">
                <div style="float:left">
                    <div style="width: 600px;font-weight:bold;color:Red;margin-top:20px;text-decoration:none">{{#link-to '' }}{{item.FirstName}}{{/link-to}}</div>
                    <div><p style="width: 600px;margin-top:10px;overflow: hidden;   text-overflow: ellipsis; display: -webkit-box; line-height: 30px; max-height: 90px; ">{{item.LastName}}</div>
                </div>

                <div style="float:right"><img {{bind-attr src=item.Image}} alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="80" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:10px" /></div>
            </div>
            <div>{{outlet}}</div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}

        **<div> @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/Partial1.cshtml")</div>**

    </script>


    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ember-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
```

**PartialView**

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">    
        <div class="container">
        Text Here
        </div>    
    </script>   

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ember-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
```

Please Give me solution for my this issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to render a Razor partial view into an Ember template? It would make more sense to have all your HTML in Ember templates and handle combining them using routes and views as appropriate

Comment: please give some samples